# How to get the hashcode generated after a element added to a hashtable?

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable

I have a hashtable which I added as key a List in the key.

How Do I return the hashcode converted from the List?

am I able to assembly back the List object element from hashtable from the generated hashcode?

thanks

Comment: Not clear.  "key a List in the key"  Show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How Do I return the hashcode converted from the List?

Call GetHashCode on the list.

> am I able to assembly back the List object element from hashtable from the generated hashcode?

Nope. There are only four billion possible hash codes, but obviously there are more than that many possible lists.  Therefore there cannot be  a way to go from the hash code to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the hashcode for the `List<T>` object that you are using in your `HashTable` (which, as far as I understand, you are using as the `key`). You can call the `GetHashCode()` function on the `List<T>` object, and retreive the hashcode from that.

To answer your other question, no, you cannot reconstruct an object from its hashcode. You *can*, however, check if two objects are the same by their hashcode. Think of a hashcode like a signature. You can (usually) verify that two signatures are from the same person (of course, there is a chance that two people may have the same signature, these are called [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_(computer_science))) However, you cannot recreate a person based on their signature.

Comment: `You can check if two people are the same if their fingerprints match` - this analogy is inaccurate. You can say that if two hashes differ, the underlying objects differ as well, but the opposite is not necessarily true.

Comment: My bad, I understand collisions exist. Long day. I'll reword it a bit :) Thank you!

Comment: A salute both you and Eric Lippert for (apparently) being able to parse the OP's question - I wasn't able to :)